# Unable to pass URL in curl with double quotes in script file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, curl

I am trying to execute a curl command in my unix script file. However, I am not able to pass the double quotes. Here are the various ways I tried:

Attempt 1: Executing as a command in a single line:

curl --fail -I -k https://www.google.com

Result: curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

I referenced the curl guide [[Link]](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Protocol_xxx_not_supported_or_di) and found the issue is because I didnt pass double quotes in the URL.

Attempt 2: curlcmd='curl --fail -I -k https://www.google.com'
eval $curlcmd

Result: Same as attempt 1

Attempt 3: curl --fail -I -k "https://www.google.com"

Result: curl: (1) Protocol ""https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Attempt 4: curl --fail -I -k /"https://www.google.com/"
This gets executed same as Attempt 1.

Result: curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Please can you help? Am I missing something?

The curl version I am using is:

```
+ curl --version
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.54.0 zlib/1.2.3.4 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap ldap pop3 rtmp rtsp smtp telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile libz UnixSockets
```

**UPDATE:**

After some changes - installing OpenSSL, etc.. I am now getting the following error:

> curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Regards,
Hari

Comment: Your `curl` looks broken if it can't handle `https`. There's nothing you can do other than install a version that isn't broken.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you suggest a possible stable version? Should I install openssl as well, along with that?

Comment: Perhaps this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683857/curl-1-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl) helps it looks like the same issue.

Comment: It depends on your distribution. If OpenSSL is missing that could be a factor. If this is from a source install that might be a mistake. Usually the package provided with your distribution has it all baked in.

Comment: @seifeddineBesbes: I had checked the link and that's where I started downloading the version.

Comment: @tadman Please can you suggest a reference link? I am using sourcefile. I was using the package provided with the distribution and it was curl 7.20.. It gives me OpenSSL unknown protocol error and when I googled it out, I realized that its because of the version, hence the source file installation attempts.

Comment: Why? What distribution are you using?

Comment: Am using Ubuntu: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release: 12.04

Comment: The package that comes with Ubuntu should have SSL support. Can you upgrade to 14.04 or 16.04 LTS? That version is now in the very last stage of support, so it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant. I am using travis and have to check the http response code using curl.